# How to disable Kerberos authentication attempts from my client?

Tags: kerberos

Every time I try to connect to a simple file share set up on Mac client - started with Mavericks, is still an issue with Yosemite (not server version), I get a long delay. There are lots of references to this problem... like:
[Why is my OSX client having so much trouble connecting to our SMB server?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127180/why-is-my-osx-client-having-so-much-trouble-connecting-to-our-smb-server/127195#127195)
and 
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6764545

The issue is that it tries to authenticate using a kerberos method and fails.

Here's an example from my console (I edited the domains):

> 5/15/15 10:39:38.144 AM NetAuthSysAgent[42091]:
>   NAHSelectionAcquireCredential The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (com.apple.NetworkAuthenticationHelper error -1765328228 -
>   acquire_kerberos failed user-name@SOME.INVALID.KERBEROS.REALM:
>   -1765328228 - unable to reach any KDC in realm SOME.INVALID.KERBEROS.REALM, tried 2 KDCs)

Once it fails, it finally pops up with the user/password prompt or allows me to select the share (if the pw is stored).

Aside from blocking netAuthSysAgent as suggested in one of the linked articles, is there a way to not have it attempt to use Kerberos?